# Which test should I use when looking at pre/post tests for a small sample?

Tags: ordinal-data, sas

I am working on an evaluation for my internship site. We do a falls prevention program for older adults that shows exercises to build lower and core body strength. Additionally, we address their fears of falling by teaching how to improve their environment, learn how to reduce their chance of injury when falling, and how to get up if they fall. Everyone gets the same intervention... there is no control in my group. I am just interested in looking at improvements in knowledge, less feelings of fear, etc from pre to post test. I am not looking to break it down by males/females either... I simply want to look at the group as a whole. Does anyone know which test (preferably in SAS) I should use? I've currently looked at each individual to see their personal improvement on each item.... is this the best way to go, or is there a better way?

PS: Each variable is measured with a likert scale.... 1-4 (strongly agree-strongly disagree)

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I would use [Wilcoxon signed-rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test), a paired-sample nonparametric test, which surely exists in SAS in some form.

Comment: If the sample size is really small nonparametric tests like the Wilcoxon signed ranked test are not very powerful. If the data are approximately normal a paired t test would be more powerful. In your case with a Likert scale in use the answers would not be normally distributed and so you may need to settle for a nonparametric approach.

Comment: My sample size is 33. Is that considered too small for the Wilcoxon? I ran the test yesterday in SAS and here is what I got:  Kruskal-Wallis Test 
Chi-Square 15.0098 
DF 4 
Asymptotic Pr > Chi-Square 0.0047 
Exact Pr >= Chi-Square 0.0011

Comment: N Sum of
Scores Expected
Under H0 Std Dev
Under H0 Mean
Score 
4 12 217.0 210.00 23.562183 18.083333 
2 4 48.0 70.00 15.885621 12.000000 
5 14 310.0 245.00 24.265686 22.142857 
3 3 19.0 52.50 13.984761 6.333333 
1 1 1.0 17.50 8.330490 1.000000 
Average scores were used for ties.